# How to load the Nether of a Bukkit-powered server into MCEdit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, mcedit

Bukkit splits world folders into separate folders for each dimension. MCEdit doesn't seem to be able to read my nether folder for that reason; it says there are no chunks in the world.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I thought MCEdit couldn't open it because it said the world contains no chunks. All you have to do is open `*_nether` with MCEdit, ignore the "no chunks" message, choose "Goto Dimension" and choose Nether.

Comment: You can click the green check mark to select this as being the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have i.e. "world_nether" - try to open this using MCEdit.